# Keyboard Layout compatibility options disapeared in Gnome 3.10?

Tags: gnome, 13.10, keyboard-layout, compatibility

I'm trying to find the keyboard layout options like in previous Ubuntu versions to activate one vital compatibility option:

> "Shift with numeric keypad keys work as in MS Windows"

But since I installed 3.10 all I see is the shortcut settings that also doesn't really works using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Bug #1218322) but that's another problem.

Comment: This has come along on the site numerous times since the release. Please use the search.

Comment: This came along numerous times but was put together with bug 1218322 that has nothing to do with that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now configure layout options in [`gnome-tweak-tool`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool), under "Typing." The "Shift with numeric keypad keys work as in MS Windows" options is found under "Miscellaneous compatibility options."

Comment: Hi Joni, I see the crtl+shift can now be used to switch language, but it prevents to use combination keys like ctrl+shift+arrow for example, do you know if there is a solution to that?

Comment: Also works for 14.04, but the tools GUI is buggy.