# Change keyboard layout in Gnome 3.10

Tags: gnome, mac, keyboard-layout, apple

I am now running Gnome 3.10 but have no idea, how to switch the Keyboard Layout (I have a Mac) there. Previously it was under keyboard but the seem to have scraped that. Does anyone know where to switch the keyboard layout?

Comment: This helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/361610/keyboard-layout-compatibility-options-disapeared-in-3-10 but certain keys are still wrong (even when choosing Apple aluminium).

Comment: Also setting `hid_apple.iso_layout=0` to `/etc/default/grub` as mentioned in https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/PageFragmentKeyboard helps at least switching the keys.